# I am building a deck using 2x12 for the frame now can I use 2x10 for the joists and still be able to pass inspection

Tags: decking

Using 2 different size boards for your frame and joists

Comment: This is _desperately_ short on details. What kind of span? What kind of spacing? Where in the world are you? What kind of load are you expecting (will there be a hot tub on the deck)? _Can_ you? Sure, why not. _Should you_? Who knows based on what info you've given us. This question is like me asking you, "Can I paint my car 2 different colors and still get my plates renewed?"

Answer (score 1):

Like as in using two different sizes in one project?

You can mix and match sizes to your heart's content, you just have to use enough that for your span and spacing they are sized appropriately to meet the requirements for strength and deflection.

I think asking this question though is a sign you should take a step back and further evaluate what you don't know before you invest a ton of time and money into this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. I used 5.5x11.75 PSLs and 2x12s for my beams and 2x6s for my joists.